# How to make collision detection in Polycode 3D

Tags: c++, collision-detection, collision, polycode

Can someone give me some example or some guidance on how to make collision detection in Polycode (I'm using it in Linux)?

I would like to check collision with "ScenePrimitive" and some mesh that I loaded into my game.

Comment: http://polycode.org/tutorial/2d_physics looks promising.  There are a ton of goole hits for polycode collision detection.  Actually, it looks like they are all 2D style.  Hmm.

Comment: Yeah, there literally isn't any simple and short example.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:

https://github.com/ivansafrin/Polycode/blob/master/Examples/C%2B%2B/Contents/3DPhysics_CollisionOnly/HelloPolycodeApp.cpp

(There's also a Lua version)

Load your mesh as you would do normally (just don't add it to the scene) and use SHAPE_MESH instead of SHAPE_BOX when adding it to the Scene as Collision Entity.

Comment: Cool, if you have any further questions you'll find me on Polycode's IRC channel ;-)